# Getting state.params in ui-router alpha for component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [angular-ui-router 1.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) . I'm trying to retrieve the params when using component, I've tried the old `$state.params` and `$stateparams` but this is not working. I can't use resolve as we are using some dynamic routing with 'ocLazyLoad'. Any suggestions?

Something like:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('test', {
    url: "/test/:id",
    component: "myComponent"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. Like the :id cannot be recognized as a parameter. (/ is missing)

```
url: "/test/:id",
```

Comment: hi Ferox, the typo was just part of the code I posted here, in the code was alright. I corrected it in the post though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking this or not but state params can be accessed like following

```
.state('question',{
   url : '/question/:id' // or url : '/question/{id}'
   controller : 'SomeController',
   component : 'someComponent'
});
```

and access the params as

```
 .controller('SomeController',function($state,$stateParams){
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;

  });
```